# Call AJAX Request in inputValidator sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, ajax, sweetalert2

I'm using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) to set up inputs and I want to check if the value I enter will be checked using `inputValidator` and use it to call an AJAX Request

```
     swal.fire({
     title: 'Enter PIN',
     input: 'password',
     confirmButtonText: 'Submit',
     showCancelButton: true,
     cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
     inputPlaceholder: "Enter PIN",
     closeOnClickOutside: false,
     inputValidator: (value) => {  
       //AJAX Request here
      //I already try to put ajax request here but it didn't work
})
```

Comment: Can your provide some more details or code you have tried so far?

Comment: Inside `inputValidator` i put AJAX Request and when it success , it needs to `return 'Success'` and it's not working

Comment: swal({   
         title: "Are you sure to delete type?",   
         text: "Selected type will be deleted successfully.!",   
         type: "warning",   
         showCancelButton: true,   
         confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   
         confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",   
         cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",   
         closeOnConfirm: false,   
         closeOnCancel: false 
     }, function(isConfirm){   
         if (isConfirm) { //AJAX Request here swal("Deleted!", "Account type has been deleted successfully.", "success");  }else {//error  }

Comment: Not like that, i want to check if the pin i enter is in the database .

Comment: https://sweetalert2.github.io/#ajax-request